# Is it possible to close a browser then reopen it in selenium to reset cache?

Tags: python, selenium, selenium-webdriver

I'm trying to close the browser then reopen it without getting any errors. 
I tried doing `driver.close()` then `webdriver.Chrome(executable_path=driver_path, options=option)` to reopen it, but it brings up `selenium.common.exceptions.InvalidSessionIdException: Message: invalid session id` 
If you're wondering why I want to do this, I'm tyring to clear all cache and cookies. I thought maybe `delete_all_cookies` might work but it doesn't.

You should be able to recreative everything with this:

```
import json
from selenium import webdriver
from contextlib import suppress

# \/\/ Webdriver & browser stuff \/\/
driver_path = ''
chrome_path = ''
option = webdriver.ChromeOptions()
option.binary_location = chrome_path
# option.add_argument("--headless")
option.add_argument("--disable-gpu")
option.add_experimental_option("excludeSwitches", ["enable-logging"])
with suppress(Exception): # Load prefrences file
    with open('drivers/Preferences') as jsonFile:
        pref = json.load(jsonFile)
    option.add_experimental_option("prefs", pref)
driver = webdriver.Chrome(executable_path=driver_path, options=option)
# /\/\ Webdriver & browser stuff /\/\

# THE MAIN PORTION \/\/
driver.get("https://example.com/")
driver.close()
webdriver.Chrome(executable_path=driver_path, options=option) # this reopens it
driver.get("https://example.org") 
# An error should come up after the above.
```

This is the error:

```
  File "g:\pbl\question.py", line 24, in <module>
    driver.get("https://example.org")
  File "C:\Users\antho\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python310\site-packages\selenium\webdriver\remote\webdriver.py", line 333, in get
    self.execute(Command.GET, {'url': url})
  File "C:\Users\antho\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python310\site-packages\selenium\webdriver\remote\webdriver.py", line 321, in execute
    self.error_handler.check_response(response)
  File "C:\Users\antho\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python310\site-packages\selenium\webdriver\remote\errorhandler.py", line 242, in check_response
    raise exception_class(message, screen, stacktrace)
selenium.common.exceptions.InvalidSessionIdException: Message: invalid session id
```

Comment: Please [edit] your question and post a [mre] demonstrating the problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You did not assign a new webdriver instance to `driver` variable. It still reference the old closed instance.

Do
`driver = webdriver.Chrome(executable_path=driver_path, options=option)` again.